# F# can't see abstract property of C# serializable abstract class

Tags: c#, f#, abstract, abstraction

Here is my serializable abstract class

```
namespace NEN_FS {
    [Serializable()]
    abstract public class NFS : IEquatable<NFS> {
        abstract public string Path { get; set; }
        public NFS() {
            Path = "";
            }
        public NFS(string path) {
            Path = path;
            }
        public override bool Equals(object obj) {
            NFS other = obj as NFS;
            return (other != null) && ((IEquatable<NFS>)this).Equals(other);
            }
        bool IEquatable<NFS>.Equals(NFS other) {
            return Path.Equals(other.Path);
            }
        public override int GetHashCode() {
            return Path != null ? Path.GetHashCode() : base.GetHashCode();
            }
        }
    }
```

What I have in F#: `let file = files.[0].` and there is no Path field.

Why is that? How can I access Path property?

Comment: I don't know about F# terminology, but in C# there's no such thing as an abstract field; that is an abstract *property*.

Comment: He refers to typing a line of `files.[0]` and placing another DOT and expecting the intellisense to show up and present a 'field'.. that is, a member 'path' as available to use.. But, you're right, thats a misnomer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huh? Strange.. maybe some bug in meta-data reading or intellisense. Try writing file.[0].Path and compiling. Sometimes the Intellisense skips something but the compiler sees whole structure right and compiles without complaints.

If not working - then maybe F# doesn't like `abstract` for some reasons unknown to me (i.e. some overall nonsense like im-possibility of instantiating an 'example object').. I'm not fluent in F# yet, but thinking about .Net itself, have you tried to define and use an interface instead of abstract base? I mean:

```
namespace NEN_FS {
    public interface class INFS : IEquatable<NFS>
    {
        string Path { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable()]
    abstract public class NFS : INFS {
        abstract public string Path { get; set; }
        public NFS() {
            Path = "";
            }
        public NFS(string path) {
            Path = path;
            }
        public override bool Equals(object obj) {
            NFS other = obj as NFS;
            return (other != null) && ((IEquatable<NFS>)this).Equals(other);
            }
        bool IEquatable<NFS>.Equals(NFS other) {
            return Path.Equals(other.Path);
            }
        public override int GetHashCode() {
            return Path != null ? Path.GetHashCode() : base.GetHashCode();
            }
        }
```

And then expose `IEnumerable<INFS> Files` instead of `IEnumerable<NFS> Files`. That way it just have to work, because interfaces are the core of access to many things..

Comment: hm... WCF provides As List(Of INFS) as obj [] to F# must I make manual :?> NFS conversion for objects ? Project available online on github : https://github.com/nCdy/NENFS

Comment: My List<INEN> is translating to object[] with svcutil, I think it's bad.

Comment: probably I think the problem is deeper and first I need resolve WCF trouble for providing array data. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12052962/wcf-providing-array-or-list-of-abstract-class-objects

Comment: So you are working with WCF and contracts? You've not said that in the question! Almost surely this is the problem of the contract definition then! Try to resolve why they are exposed as object - maybe it is that the INFS/NFS are not DataContract or MarhalByRef etc ?

Comment: check another question in the link above, it's harder, it shell work as public NEN_FS.NFS[] ls() but it fails with some strange reason I can not understand it so far.

Answer (score 0):

What you're experiencing is an intellisense-related bug (or else just a basic incapability of intellisense). F# is perfectly capable of "seeing" the `Path` property. Just try finishing the line `let file = files.[0].Path` and compile (or write it in fsi). You'll see that everything goes fine.

Intellisense is a great tool, but sometimes it doesn't work quite right (I get it now and then when working in C# as well). Relying on it to always report the most up-to-date and complete information will cause some confusion now and then.

Comment: @МарияШарапова: I just tried this where `files` is a `NFS list`. It both compiles and executes in fsi. Are you sure that `files` has a type which supports indexing?

Comment: Ken - my 'personal favourite' in the intellisense is [\[EditorBrowsable(Never)\]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute.aspx) :)