# Providing array or list of class objects via WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, abstraction, svcutil.exe

**Any example of WCF client server providing of List or Array of custom class objects would help me!** But here is what I have got so far:

Here is my class system I want to provide

```
namespace NEN_Server.FS {
    [Serializable()]
    public class XFS {
        private List<NFS> files;
        public XFS() {
            files = new List<NFS>();
            }
        public List<NFS> Files {
            get { return files; }
            set { files = value; }
            }
        }
    }
```

where NFS is

```
namespace NEN_FS {
    public interface INFS : IEquatable<NFS> {
        string Path { get; set; }
        }
    [Serializable()]
    abstract public class NFS : INFS {
        abstract public string Path { get; set; }
        public NFS() {
            Path = "";
            }
        public NFS(string path) {
            Path = path;
            }
        public override bool Equals(object obj) {
            NFS other = obj as NFS;
            return (other != null) && ((IEquatable<NFS>)this).Equals(other);
            }
        bool IEquatable<NFS>.Equals(NFS other) {
            return Path.Equals(other.Path);
            }
        public override int GetHashCode() {
            return Path != null ? Path.GetHashCode() : base.GetHashCode();
            }
        }
    }
```

and providing method is :

```
namespace NEN_Server.WCF {
    public class NEN : INEN {
        private MMF mmf;
        public NEN() {
            mmf = new MMF();
            }
        public string GetRandomCustomerName() {
            return mmf.MMFS.Files[0].Path;
            }
        public NFS[] ls() {
            return mmf.MMFS.Files.ToArray();
            }
```

Interface is

```
<ServiceContract>
Public Interface INEN
    <OperationContract>
    Function GetRandomCustomerName() As String
    <OperationContract()>
    Function ls() As NFS()
```

and finally I do:

```
%svcutil% /language:cs /out:NEN_Protocol\NEN.cs http://localhost:8080/NEN_Server
```

it generates :

```
public NEN_FS.NFS[] ls()
{
    return base.Channel.ls();
}
```

I call it in my client application let files = nen.ls() and it fails with :

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
```

on `return base.Channel.ls();` line of code.

**Note** that providing string `mmf.MMFS.Files[0].Path;` works just fine

Why? What am I doing wrong? :)

All the code is available on GitHub : https://github.com/nCdy/NENFS

Comment: Q1: why don't you use data contacts, which is "native" for WCF?
Q2: what the length of returning array is?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've to go offline for a 3-4hrs, but I'll surely look at it afterwards if noone answers yet. Quick hint - 'The connection was closed unexpectedly' suggests that the callback/service crashed at the server. Attach debugger there or check the logs and retry, you will probably get some extra information

Comment: @Dennis Q1: data contacts? I just don't know about them. (or do you mean System.Data.Services?) Q2: it's one element but it doesn't returns in wcf client because it fails to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me, that fault reason is here: `abstract public class NFS`.
The first, consider using of [data contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx) with WCF:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
abstract public class NFS : INFS 
{
  [DataMember]
  abstract public string Path { get; set; }

  // the rest of code here
}
```

The second, specify [known types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx) for your data contract. Serializers on both side of a communication channel have to know, how to seralize/deserialize concrete `NFS`' descendant type:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
[KnownType(typeof(NFS1))]
[KnownType(typeof(NFS2))]
abstract public class NFS : INFS 
{
  [DataMember]
  abstract public string Path { get; set; }

  // the rest of code here
}

public class NFS1 : NFS {}
public class NFS2 : NFS {}
```